# Make Python Project Into Command Line Tool

Tags: python, linux, command-line, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a python project with multiple files and a cmd.py which uses argparse to parse the arguments, in the other files there are critical functions. What I want to do is: I want to make it so that if in the command line I were to put `cmd -p hello.txt` it runs that python file.

I was thinking that I could just simply move the cmd.py file to somewhere like `/usr/bin/` or some other directory included in the `$PATH`, however since I have other files which work with my `cmd.py`, there will be multiple files in my `/usr/bin`.

Another thing that I could do is to make a symbolic link between the `cmd.py` and `/usr/bin/cmd` like this: `ln -s /path/to/cmd.py /usr/bin/cmd`, but then where do i put the cmd.py? and is this best practice?

Note: I intend for this to work on Linux and MacOS X, not windows

Comment: There may be a little primarily opinion based. You can put this `cmd.py`, with all the peripherals inside `/usr/bin`, or better `/usr/local/bin`, or create a separated folder inside `/usr/bin` or somewhere you wish then add it into $PATH environment variable.

Comment: I generally use a `~/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to define a set of entry points in `setup.py` and let the packaging infrastructure do the heavy lifting for you.

```
setup(
    # ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['cmd = cmd:main'],
    }
)
```

This requires `setuptools`.

Here is some documentation for this facility: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

For one thing I don't recommend installation in `/usr/bin` as that's where system programs go. `/usr/local/bin` or another custom directory added to `$PATH` could be appropriate.

As for getting it to run like a typical program, name it `cmd`, wherever you put it, as the extension is not necessary, and add this line to the top of the program:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

(You may want to specify `python3` instead of just `python` if you want to ensure Python 3.x is used.)

Then it can be made executable with `chmod +x <path to your program>`. Ensure that you have the necessary privileges to do this (i.e. `sudo` may be necessary).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add a folder to your path.

   - in .bashrc add following
   - export PATH=[New_Folder_Path]:$PATH
2. put the python program in your path_folder created at step 1.
3. make it executable : chmod u+x [filename]
4. open a new terminal, and you should be able to call the python program
5. NOTE: make sure to put the shebang in your python-file : #!/usr/bin/env python3